# How can I change a field in a SQL server database that's set to "Read Only Cell"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL database that has a table with a field set to "Read Only" when I look at it through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.

I need to change some data within that field manually but I can't see any properties that I can change that will let me override this.

Will I need to write a sql script on the table to do this or is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: Why is the field read/only if you need to modify it?

Comment: @lassevk - not sure as I didn't originally set up the database. It's basically a configuration table that wouldn't normally change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the datatype of the field? You may not be able to "type" into it if its of an ntext or image datatype and management studio can't handle the size of it.

In that case you might have no option but to perform an update as follows.

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = 'NewValue' WHERE PrimaryKeyId = PrimaryKeyValue
```

Comment: That will be the issue then. Xml is a complex datatype that would be difficult to edit in a cell. I'm afraid you will need to do this in an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 2):

The field is most likely "read-only" because it contains a calculated value.

If that's the case, you would have to change calculation in the table definition to change it's value.

Comment: I can't see a Calculation property for this within SQL server management studio express ??

Comment: I just read in another comment that the field type is XML. Maybe you just cannot edit XML directly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, I think that seems to be the case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will occur when you set a particular field as Primary Key and you set it into 'Is Identity' is true, that means that field will automatically incremented whenever an insertion is takes placed...So better to check whether it is auto increment or not.. If it is ,then change that property 'Is Idenitity' as false.

Answer (score 0):

In an SQL query I had once, the query I used to generate the table to edit included a join to a table on a "Server Object", specifically a linked server. This marked the cells as read only, even though the table on which I was actually going to change the data wasn't on the linked server.

My resolution: Luckily I was able to adjust the query so I didn't need to do the JOIN with a linked table and then I could edit the cells.

Suggestion: Check your query for linked servers or other odd statements that may lock your table.

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger in order to prevent this column updating:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateRecord ON my_table
AFTER UPDATE AS UPDATE my_table
SET [CreatedDate] = ((SELECT TOP 1 [CreatedDate] FROM Deleted d where d.[id]=[id]))
```